# Sails, grunt-contrib-watch is not working with jshint

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js, jshint, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm new to sails. I'm using:

- sails@0.10.5
- grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3
- grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0
- jshint@2.5.11

I've been starting my server using either `sails lift` or `sails lift --verbose`. According to the sails documentation `grunt default` is ran. The first task is `compileAssets`. Which starts with `jshint`. My `compileAssets` tasks ends with a `watch` command.

When a file is changed that is being *watched*, `syncAssets` is ran. `syncAssets` is identical to my `compileAssets` task. They both start with `jshint`.

The problem is that while `syncAssets` is running, it is not reporting any `jshint` errors in the console, and/or stopping the `syncAssets` task so I have no idea if my code as compiled with out looking at the source.

Then I must restart the server to find the error, since `compileAssets` will print the `jshint` error.

Is something configured incorrectly in my tasks?

*tasks/register/default.js* -- Unchanged

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['compileAssets', 'linkAssets',  'watch']);
};
```

*tasks/register/syncAssets.js*

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('syncAssets', [
    'jshint',
    'bower',
    'clean:dev',
    'copy:dev',
    'exec:compileTemplates',
    'exec:compilePartials',
    'compass'
    ]);
};
```

*tasks/register/compileAssets.js*

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
    'jshint',
    'bower',
    'clean:dev',
    'copy:dev',
    'exec:compileTemplates',
    'exec:compilePartials',
    'compass'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Try posting on here. They're great with answering questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Comment: Thanks. I'll try posting on there.